# Unexpected behavior of arraystretch and figures in table cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

Using the `graphicx` and the `includegraphics` command, I want to place a figure in a table cell. In addition, I use the `arraystretch` command the increase the padding of cells. Unfortunately, I get a strange alignment behavior, if I use all in common:

[image]

The text in the second row should also be aligned at the cell's top. I used nearly only native latex stuff, so I don't think it is something about package correlations. Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\convetionsSymbolWidth}
\setlength{\convetionsSymbolWidth}{3.5cm}

\newlength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}
\setlength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{-\convetionsSymbolWidth}
\addtolength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{4\tabcolsep}

\begingroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\convetionsSymbolWidth}
           p{\convetionsDescriptionWidth} }
            \hline\hline

            Text & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
            placerat arcu lorem, at volutpat ante lobortis in. Nullam at velit et
            nisi pellentesque molestie. Pellentesque pretium egestas nunc vel
            varius. Proin non augue id arcu condimentum sodales vel ut leo. Morbi
            non ipsum nunc.\\

            \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline     

            \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{structureIconArtifactsProxyWorkload.pdf}
            \newline
            {\footnotesize \emph{\textcolor{gray}{$\rightarrow$ Fig.~2.6, p.~31}}} &        
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
            placerat arcu lorem, at volutpat ante lobortis in. Nullam at velit et
            nisi pellentesque molestie. Pellentesque pretium egestas nunc vel
            varius. Proin non augue id arcu condimentum sodales vel ut leo. Morbi
            non ipsum nunc.
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+2ex}{%
     \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]%
          {structureIconArtifactsProxyWorkload.pdf}}
```

Comment: Great, thank you, this works! Could you also explain why :-)?

Comment: the image is for TeX  "_one_ big character" which has the same baseline as the first line in the next cell. Compare `{\Huge X} x` which shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is use of package `adjustbox` and add `valign=t` (vertically align top) into the `\includegraphic` option. Remove [demo] from the `graphicx` package for true image

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[pdftex,demo]{graphicx}           % remove demo for true image
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}               % <--- new 
\begin{document}

\newlength{\convetionsSymbolWidth}
\setlength{\convetionsSymbolWidth}{3.5cm}

\newlength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}
\setlength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{-\convetionsSymbolWidth}
\addtolength{\convetionsDescriptionWidth}{4\tabcolsep}

\begingroup
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\convetionsSymbolWidth}
           p{\convetionsDescriptionWidth} }
            \hline\hline

            Text & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
            placerat arcu lorem, at volutpat ante lobortis in. Nullam at velit et
            nisi pellentesque molestie. Pellentesque pretium egestas nunc vel
            varius. Proin non augue id arcu condimentum sodales vel ut leo. Morbi
            non ipsum nunc.\\
            \arrayrulecolor{gray}\hline   

 \includegraphics[valign=t,width=\marginparwidth]{structureIconArtifactsProxyWorkload.pdf}
           \newline
            {\footnotesize \emph{\textcolor{gray}{$\rightarrow$ Fig.~2.6, p.~31}}} &        
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
            placerat arcu lorem, at volutpat ante lobortis in. Nullam at velit et
            nisi pellentesque molestie. Pellentesque pretium egestas nunc vel
            varius. Proin non augue id arcu condimentum sodales vel ut leo. Morbi
            non ipsum nunc. 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```